# How do I use FloydWarshallShortestPaths in Jgrapht

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

I want to find shortest path from a node to all other nodes in my graph. How do I use FloydWarshallShortestPaths available in Jgrapht to do this.

```
 List path =
                FloydWarshallShortestPaths.getShortestPaths(city1);
```

this doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The method getShortestPaths is not static. You need to generate an instance of the type FloydWarshallShortestPaths first.

http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/FloydWarshallShortestPaths.html#getShortestPaths(V)